# Enable templating language (e.g., Liquid) syntax highlighting but keep native (html/css) commenting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype, comments

I just started working with Jekyll, which uses Liquid. As a templating language, Liquid is embedded into files of other types (*e.g.,* HTML, CSS, or Markdown). Vim handles this sort of dual syntax highlighting admirably – when `set filetype=liquid` in, say, an HTML file, it *preserves* the HTML highlighting while *additionally* highlighting Liquid code.

But Liquid also has its own comment markers, which are distinct from HTML's, CSS's, and Markdown's. And when I want to comment something out in a `.css.liquid` file, more often than not, what I'm trying to do is make a `/* CSS comment */`, *not* a `{{ comment }}Liquid comment{{ endcomment }}`.

Unfortunately, I rely on tpope’s [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) to comment stuff out, and that plugin relies on the filetype-specific `commentstring` setting to determine how to wrap comments.

So my question is, is there any way to enable Liquid syntax highlighting while keeping the native `commentstring` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/liquid.vim` containing:

```
if expand('%:e:e') == 'css.liquid'
    set commentstring=/*\ %s\ */
endif
```

Which will change style of comments to `/* ... */` only for Liquid files with `.css.liquid` extension.

Comment: I modified this to read `=~ 'css'`, since Jekyll does away with the `.liquid` extension altogether. Would not have known about the `after/` directory, though. Thanks!